# PDO unbuffered queries multiple query error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I get an error when trying to perform a query that returns about 100,000 rows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.'
```

The error seems to suggest that multiple queries are running at the same time, but upon checking the MySQL log this is not the case:

```
150226 15:10:28     3 Connect   root@localhost on Project
            3 Query SELECT * FROM Data WHERE posted > '2015-02-01 14:52:28' AND posted < '2015-02-19 18:36:56'
150226 15:11:00     3 Quit
```

What are the causes of an error like this?

Turning on buffered queries is not an option because of the size of the result returned.

Comment: some php code might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that mysql only allows for one outstanding cursor at a given time. By using the fetch() method and not consuming all the pending data, you are leaving a cursor open.

The recommended approach is to consume all the data using the fetchAll() method. An alternative is to use the closeCursor() method.